# Recursion time exceeded, when I try to test with a large amount of data

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance-testing

I am trying with thousands of cases. Every time I do **linear, sort, heap search**, I want to see performance of them. When I make a list from input, I just copy three times and make a new list to put in the **linear, sort, heap search** in order. 
When I researched about recursion, I found out that only around **900 recursion is possible** in python. 
How can I test more than 900 recursion?

```
import copy
import heapq
import sys
import threading
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer, timeit
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


class Vertex:

    def __init__(self, vertex_id):
        self.vertex_id = vertex_id
        self.key = float('inf')
        self.edge_list = list()
        self.visited = False

    def is_not_visited(self):
        if self.visited is False:
            return True
        return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.key < other.key

class Edge:

    def __init__(self, to_vertex, weight):
        self.to_vertex = to_vertex
        self.weight = weight


def load_num_case():
    return int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())


def find_the_smallest_vertex(queue):
    min = queue[0]
    index = 0
    for x in range(0, len(queue)):
        if min.key > queue[x].key:
            min = queue[x]
            index = x

    return queue.pop(index)


def sort_and_return_smallest(queue):
    queue.sort(key=lambda x:x.key)
    #queue = sorted(queue, key=lambda x: x.key)
    ## not working
    current = queue.pop(0)
    return current


def sort_daikstra(c_num, start_vertex, end_vertex, vertices_list):
    queue = []
    visited_list = list()
    current_ver = start_vertex
    current_ver.key = 0
    queue.append(current_ver)

    while queue:
        current_ver = sort_and_return_smallest(queue)
        if current_ver.visited is True:
            continue
        for edge in current_ver.edge_list:
            if edge.to_vertex.is_not_visited():
                queue.append(edge.to_vertex)
                total_weight = current_ver.key + edge.weight
                if total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key:
                    edge.to_vertex.key = total_weight
                    edge.to_vertex.parent = current_ver
        current_ver.visited = True
        visited_list.append(current_ver)

    for x in visited_list:
        if x.vertex_id == end_vertex.vertex_id:
            sys.stdout.write("CASE {0}: {1}".format(c_num, x.key))


def heap_daikstra(c_num, start_vertex, end_vertex, vertices_list):
    queue = []
    visited_list = list()
    queue.append(start_vertex)
    current_ver = start_vertex
    current_ver.key = 0

    while queue:
        current_ver = heapq.heappop(queue)

        if current_ver.visited is True:
            continue
        for edge in current_ver.edge_list:
            if edge.to_vertex.is_not_visited():
                heapq.heappush(queue, edge.to_vertex)
                total_weight = current_ver.key + edge.weight
                if total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key:
                    edge.to_vertex.key = total_weight
                    edge.to_vertex.parent = current_ver
        current_ver.visited = True
        visited_list.append(current_ver)

    for x in visited_list:
        if x.vertex_id == end_vertex.vertex_id:
            sys.stdout.write("CASE {0}: {1}".format(c_num, x.key))


def linear_daikstra(c_num, start_vertex, end_vertex, vertices_list):
    queue = []
    visited_list = list()
    current_ver = start_vertex
    current_ver.key = 0
    queue.append(start_vertex)

    while queue:
        current_ver = find_the_smallest_vertex(queue)
        if current_ver.visited is True:
            continue
        for edge in current_ver.edge_list:
            if edge.to_vertex.is_not_visited():
                queue.append(edge.to_vertex)
                total_weight = current_ver.key + edge.weight
                if total_weight < edge.to_vertex.key:
                    edge.to_vertex.key = total_weight
                    edge.to_vertex.parent = current_ver
        current_ver.visited = True
        visited_list.append(current_ver)

    for x in visited_list:
        if x.vertex_id == end_vertex.vertex_id:
            sys.stdout.write("CASE {0}: {1}".format(c_num, x.key))




def main():
    case_list = list()
    n_case = load_num_case()

    for c_num in range(n_case):
        vertices_list = list()
        num_ver_edge = sys.stdin.readline()
        num_ver_edge = (num_ver_edge.rstrip('\n')).split(" ")
        vertex_num = int(num_ver_edge[0])
        edge_num = int(num_ver_edge[1])
        for v_num in range(vertex_num):
            vertex = Vertex(v_num)
            vertices_list.append(vertex)
        start_end = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
        start_end = start_end.split(" ")
        start_vertex = int(start_end[0])
        end_vertex = int(start_end[1])

        for edge_num in range(edge_num):
            from_to_weight = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
            from_to_weight = from_to_weight.split(" ")
            from_vertex = int(from_to_weight[0])
            to_vertex = int(from_to_weight[1])
            weight = int(from_to_weight[2])
            edge = Edge(vertices_list[to_vertex], weight)
            vertices_list[from_vertex].edge_list.append(edge)

        linear_list = copy.deepcopy(vertices_list)
        sort_list = copy.deepcopy(vertices_list)
        heap_list = copy.deepcopy(vertices_list)


        linear_start_time = datetime.now()
        linear_daikstra(c_num, linear_list[start_vertex], linear_list[end_vertex], linear_list)
        print("    Linear - %s seconds -" % (datetime.now()  - linear_start_time))

        sort_start_time = time.time()
        sort_daikstra(c_num, sort_list[start_vertex], sort_list[end_vertex], sort_list)
        print("    Sort - %s seconds -" % (time.time() - sort_start_time))

        heap_start_time = time.time()
        heap_daikstra(c_num, vertices_list[start_vertex], vertices_list[end_vertex], heap_list)
        print("    Heap - %s seconds -" % (time.time() - heap_start_time))






if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: You can increase the recursion depth but you might end up blowing up your stack which is why the limit is there in the first place

Comment: If you need to recurse more than 900 times, honestly, you shouldn't be using recursion unless you can guarantee that it will me TCO'd (and I don't think Python had any such guarantee, or that it's even attempts the optimization). You'll want to look into a iterative alternative solution instead. You can increase the stack size as a temporary solution, but that's just kicking the can down the road a little ways.

Comment: CPython definitely does not use tail-call optimization. Anyway OP, just use an iterative solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying you *should* do this... but to directly answer your question, you can use `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` and adjust the limit according to your situation.